# Is there a function to tell if two probability vectors' max values are in the same dimension?

Tags: probability-distributions, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Is there a method or function to tell two probability vectors' max values are in the same dimension?

Or

Is there a bound for the angle of two normalized probability vector which their max values are in the same dimension?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second question:   if the size of the vector is at most $N$, then something can be said. Let $m_1,m_2$ be the maximal values; they are  at least $1/N$. If they are in the same dimension, the inner product is at least $m_1m_2$. The square of $L^2$ norm of the $i$th vector, $i=1,2$, is at most $\sum p_k^2 \le m_i \sum p_k = m_i$. Thus, the cosine of the angle is at least 
$$\frac{m_1m_2}{\sqrt{m_1}\sqrt{m_2}} = \sqrt{m_1m_2} \ge \frac{1}{N}$$

---

Without control on the size, two such vectors can be arbitrarily close to being orthogonal. Take 
$$\left(\frac2n , 0, \frac1n, 0, \frac1n,\dots, 0, \frac1n\right) $$
and 
$$\left(\frac2n ,  \frac1n, 0, \frac1n, 0, \dots,   \frac1n, 0\right) $$
The inner product of these vectors is $4/n^2$. The $L^2$ norm of each is of the order $1/\sqrt{n} $. Hence, the cosine of angle is of order $1/n$, which can be arbitrarily small.

---

For the first question: I'm afraid there is no method other than to locate the maximal elements and note their positions. Aggregate quantities like $L^2$ nor and inner product cannot tell exactly where the maximum happens, since the position of maximal entry can change under a slight perturbation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So let me get this straight. For the second
property, only if we know the max values are in the same dimension it will work. However, if two vectors' inner product is bigger than  
1/n, we cannot infer their max values are in the same dimension.

Is that right?